# Group a pivoted table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, pivot-table

I want to group the following table by two ranges. To do this, i pivoted the table, but it shows me some NULL fields. How can i group the table so it shows me only the not null values?

Here is the SQL Query:

```
SELECT RangoCuotas, [0   -21  ],[21  -42  ],[42  -79  ],[79  -158 ],[158  -9999]
FROM(
    SELECT IdTasaSeguro, Valor, CONVERT(CHAR(4),MontoMinimo)+'-'+CONVERT(CHAR(4),MontoMaximo) AS RangoMonto, CONVERT(CHAR(4),CASE WHEN CuotaMin = 0 THEN 1 ELSE CuotaMin END)+'-'+CONVERT(CHAR(4),CuotaMax) AS RangoCuotas
    FROM [BEFE_SistemaGestionMDP].[dbo].[TasaSeguro]
    WHERE IdTipoSeguro = 1
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT 
(
SUM(Valor) FOR RangoMonto IN ([0   -21  ],[21  -42  ],[42  -79  ],[79  -158 ],[158 -9999])
) AS PivotTable1
GROUP BY RangoCuotas,[0   -21  ],[21  -42  ],[42  -79  ],[79  -158 ],[158 -9999]
```

[image: Table Result]

Comment: Going to just take a guess, remove `IdTasaSeguro` from your subquery. You're not using it in your pivot so it's most likely forcing the multiple rows, also get rid of the extra group by after you pivot, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you would use `SELECT *` for the main `SELECT` statement then you'll see the reason.**

Solution: remove from `(...) SourceTable` derived table unnecessary columns (ex. `IdTasaSeguro`)

```
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Valor, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4),MontoMinimo)+'-'+CONVERT(CHAR(4),MontoMaximo) AS RangoMonto, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4),CASE WHEN CuotaMin = 0 THEN 1 ELSE CuotaMin END)+'-'+CONVERT(CHAR(4),CuotaMax) AS RangoCuotas
    FROM [BEFE_SistemaGestionMDP].[dbo].[TasaSeguro]
    WHERE IdTipoSeguro = 1
) AS SourceTable
```